# With start up to send to the database

Tags: php, mysqli

That's how I'm new in here on the website so it would be super if you'll tell if I need to do something because I am very new in here ..

What I have problem with my website it's header and yes a second error that I do not get to go up in some manner whatsoever.

that's how I'm going to build my own forum since I do not really bother to spend phpbbforum or what it says and. This is how I try lie same html with php code and it works not at all in some way.

i have try so here:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

        <?php
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `titel`, `bruger_id`, `dato`, `tekst`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $kategori, $titel, $bruger_id, $tekst);
                $kategori = $_POST["kategori"];
                $titel = $_POST["titel"];
                $bruger_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
                $tekst = $_POST["tekst_2"];

                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                header ('Location: ./bruger-forum');
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        ?>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Titel</p></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="titel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Kategori</p></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="kategori">
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT id, beskrivelse FROM forum_kategorier";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                    while(list($id_katogori, $beskrivelse) = $result->fetch_row())
                    {
                        echo "<option value=\"$id_katogori\">$beskrivelse</option>";  
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <textarea name="tekst_2" style="width:500px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opret indhold" name="godkendt_indhold">
    </form>
```

*but here I did not click the submit button*

**errors are here**

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jesperbo/public_html/xx.dk/bruger_forum_opretindhold.php:26) in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xx.dk/bruger_forum_opretindhold.php on line 50

I've also try to do it this way but there is therefore also error out.

i try here agani :)

```
<form action="http://xxx.dk/bruger-forum-godkendt/" method="post">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Titel</p></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="titel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Kategori</p></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="kategori">
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT id, beskrivelse FROM forum_kategorier";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                    while(list($id_katogori, $beskrivelse) = $result->fetch_row())
                    {
                        echo "<option value=\"$id_katogori\">$beskrivelse</option>";  
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <textarea name="tekst_2" style="width:500px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Opret indhold" name="godkendt_indhold">
    </form>
```

**send infomation on here to**

```
<?php
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `titel`, `bruger_id`, `dato`, `tekst`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $kategori, $titel, $bruger_id, $tekst);
                $kategori = $_POST["kategori"];
                $titel = $_POST["titel"];
                $bruger_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
                $tekst = $_POST["tekst_2"];

                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                header ('Location: ../bruger-forum');
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        ?>
```

errors here!
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jesperbo/public_html/xxx.dk/bruger_forum_opretindhold_godkendt.php on line 2

and i have try

```
header ('Location: http://xxx.dk/bruger-forum/');
```

and

```
header ('Location: ../bruger-forum');
```

The first thing I show up to you I want out when it has sent infomation to the database then it should just "jump" back to the forum page .. I build my url up. htaccess

Feel free to ask if there is anything but as I said I come from Denmark and **is not exactly the best of English**

**Thanks for you look!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is that you are triying to set a header after sending some input to the browser. 
if you want to redirect you can either move your code to the begining and send the `header('location:...);` BEFORE anything.

or use something like `echo "<script>window.location = 'yourURL'</script>"`

and the fatal error, its because your object is not being created.

Comment: Okay but if I use it as a show not the rest of my website ie footer and header and look like

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're writing to the header, it needs to be before anything else is output. In this case, it's failing because of the `<form>` tag at the top of the page - if you move that to just above the `<table>` tag, that should help.

Secondly, your `Fatal Error` message means that your database connection isn't working; where do you define `$mysqli`? Are you sure that all the information you need is correct? Try adding a little debugging information around the connection code to see where it's failing.

Comment: Thank you .. :) I tag out tag from the last I write .. :) I go there from. but the little it is not in the database how can it be?

if I may ask stupid?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. The Fatal Error means that your query isn't being passed to the database properly; that's normally because the connection isn't working properly. In the part of the code where you create $mysqli, try adding `$mysqli->connect_error` to make sure that you're connecting to the database.

Comment: this her er my database:

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect('db8.meebox.net', 'jesperbo_xxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxx');

/* Tjek, om der opstod en fejl */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl ved forbindelsen: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
    exit();
}
?>

Comment: Where are you creating $mysqli? Is it in the same file as the code that's giving you the fatal error? Or is it in a function that you're calling from there?

Comment: Sorry what I just wrote it when I file I just include for when I need the database.

what do you mean completely with creating $ mysql. you have an example. on where I can find a good MySQLI connent to the database or what?

Comment: So you include it in the file when you want to connect to the database? That should be fine, then, as it should give you an error message if it doesn't connect. I think I'm at the limit of what I can help with! You might want to create a separate question for that part - if you include all the PHP code for the file where the query isn't working, someone else might have an idea as to what's not working.

Comment: yes ok but it just will not put into the database but in fashion it would like to send me back to the site :)

Comment: Have you tried printing out the SQL of your INSERT statement, and entering that directly into the database?

Comment: ok; I'm terribly confused now. Are you saying that the SQL works if you don't use the header("Location") line?

Comment: <?php
include("include/db.php/db.php");
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `forum_traede` (`kategori_id`, `titel`, `bruger_id`, `dato`, `tekst`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)"))
{
 $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $kategori, $titel, $bruger_id, $tekst);
 $kategori = $_POST["kategori"];
 $titel = $_POST["titel"];
 $bruger_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
 $tekst = $_POST["tekst_2"];
 
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
  header('Location: http://xx.dk/bruger-forum/');
}
else
{
 echo 'lala: ' . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
then it will not work and lie into database but just send me back again

Comment: If you take the header line out, does it write successfully to the database?

Comment: What do you mean completely? Understand not just what you mean. sorry but is not quite how you mean it :)

Comment: In the PHP you've just posted, if you remove the `header` line, does it update the database? Basically - what is the output of that PHP? Does it show you the 'lala' error message? If not, is the database updated at all?

Comment: If I swap out the header with an echo then it would be into the database but if I do not do it then just send me back again.

Comment: can you give me your email so I can just contact you? because I think we misunderstand each other.

Comment: Surely; mail me at stackoverflow [at] digression.co.uk

Comment: how do I, so to them that I think he help me get something out of this?